# How can I put every object as an option in select tag in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm making an API call, which gives me an array response. I'm pushing its items in another array to make it globally accessible. The thing is that I need to put every object names from the array in the select tag as an options, but I have no idea why it isn't working. Here's my code and thanks in advance!

```
let categories =  [];
class GetCategories extends React.Component {
 render() {
     fetch('https://opentdb.com/api_category.php')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
         data.trivia_categories.forEach(item => categories.push(item));

     });

     return (
         <div className="category-options">
             <select className='selectCategory' name="difficulty">
                 {categories.forEach(category => <option value={category.id}>{category.name}</option>)}
             </select>
         </div>
     );
 };
}

export default class WelcomePage extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
       <div id="input-container">
         <GetCategories />
       </div>
     );
 } 
}
```

Response of the API call:

```
0: {id: 9, name: "General Knowledge"}
1: {id: 10, name: "Entertainment: Books"}
2: {id: 11, name: "Entertainment: Film"}
3: {id: 12, name: "Entertainment: Music"}
4: {id: 13, name: "Entertainment: Musicals & Theatres"}
5: {id: 14, name: "Entertainment: Television"}
6: {id: 15, name: "Entertainment: Video Games"}
7: {id: 16, name: "Entertainment: Board Games"}
8: {id: 17, name: "Science & Nature"}
9: {id: 18, name: "Science: Computers"}
```

Comment: What does " it isn't working" mean?

Comment: @AndyRay The elements doesn't appear in the select tag

Comment: No, it doesn't answers my question

Comment: What's wrong with your code is that nothing is triggering a re-render of your component. You need to use state in react. [The React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and the question @AndyRay commented will help you.

Comment: you need to use `map` instead of `forEach` on `categories`. `forEach` returns undefined.

Comment: Thank you Raj, I'll try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use state and don't fetch the data in render() rather use componentWillMount() lifecycle and it will work

```
class GetCategories extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {categories: []};
    }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api_category.php')
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(data => {   
          this.setState({
             categories: data.trivia_categories
          });
    });
  }
  
 render() {
     return (
         <div className="category-options">
             <select className='selectCategory' name="difficulty">
                 {this.state.categories.map(category => {
                   return (
                   <option value={category.id}>
                     {category.name}
                   </option>
                   )
                 })}
             </select>
         </div>
     );
 };
}

class WelcomePage extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
       <div id="input-container">
         <GetCategories />
       </div>
     );
 } 
}


ReactDOM.render(<WelcomePage />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: `componentWillMount` was deprecated in 2018, and you should use `componentDidMount` instead. Otherwise I think this is the appropriate answer. https://dev.to/torianne02/componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount-5f0n

Comment: Also I think you can simplify this code a bit, by simply calling `this.setState({ categories: data.trivia_categories })` in the `then` callback.

Comment: thanks a lot, bro for the suggestions I have made the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `map` instead of `forEach` on `categories`. `forEach` returns undefined.

Specifically, change this part of your jsx:

```
<select className='selectCategory' name="difficulty">
   {categories.map(category => <option value={category.id}>{category.name}</option>)}
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I've tried it too and It doesn't work

Comment: @NikaNabakhteveli it was worth a try, good luck :)

Comment: The original code is fine in the sense that OP is using `forEach` properly. The real problem is the fact that fetching the data inside the `render` method, as well as not using state, means the component is not re-rendered when the (asynchronous) fetch call finally returns.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could make some changes in the `map` loop, for example you could use object destructing which make code prettier and easier to read.

You should try something like this:

```js
<select className='selectCategory' name="difficulty">
  {categories.map(({ id, name}, idx) => (
    <option value={id} key={idx}>{name}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```